# Python validation when utilizing .append

Tags: python, validation, append

I am unsure how to add validation to my input, specifically a presence check, which looks like this:

```
team1.append(input("Please enter the name of a team member: "))
```

Normally with more traditional inputs, my validation would look like this:

```
exampleInput=input("enter input")
while exampleInput=="":
exampleInput=input("enter input")
```

But that doesn't seem to work, as the validation does nothing if I try something like this:

```
team1.append(input("Please enter the name of a team member: "))
while team1.append(input)=="":
team1.append(input("Please enter the name of a team member: "))
```

I'm not sure how I could add any sort of validation to this. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Get the value. 2. Validate the value. 3. Append to `team1` if the validation is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
inp = input("Please enter the name of a team member: ")
if inp != "":
    team1.append(inp)
```

Comment: I did the actual validation slightly differently, but the method of having there being a separate input that handles the validation before it gets added did work. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve: `team` implies that you want to append `multiple` members, ignore empty lines, and have a way to exit the loop: the logic presented so far will stop once one valid member (i.e. not empty space) is entered, hence you'll get a list of size 1. 
For example, I think this would work for that purpose:

```
team1 = []
this_member = ""
while True:
    this_member = input("Please enter the name of a team member: ").strip()
    if this_member != "":
        if this_member.upper() == "EXIT":
            break
        team1.append(this_member)
    
print(team1)
```

So an interaction would be:

```
Please enter the name of a team member: Paul
Please enter the name of a team member: George
Please enter the name of a team member: 
Please enter the name of a team member: 
Please enter the name of a team member: Alan
Please enter the name of a team member: EXIT
['Paul', 'George', 'Alan']
```